# Extracting number from string only when string is present in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I am trying to get extract a chain of numbers that might proceed a list of characters within a data frame. If there are no characters nothing needs to be done to the cell. If there are characters then I want the chares to be the take out. I want the end result to be the same column but with no characters. see example.

Before:

| ID | Price | Item Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3.60 | a/b 80986 |
| 2 | 4.30 | 45772 |
| 3 | 0.60 | fF/6 9778 |
| 4 | 9.78 | 48989 |
| 5 | 3.44 | \ 545 |
| 6 | 3.44 | r. 509 |

Result:

| ID | Price | Item Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3.60 | 80986 |
| 2 | 4.30 | 45772 |
| 3 | 0.60 | 9778 |
| 4 | 9.78 | 48989 |
| 5 | 3.44 | 545 |
| 6 | 3.44 | 509 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html?highlight=str%20extract#pandas.Series.str.extract) with the regex pattern `r'(?:^|\s)(\d+)`:

- `(?:^|\s)` matches  the beginning of the string (`'^'`) or (`'|'`) any whitespace character (`'\s'`) without capturing it (`(?:...)`)
- `(\d+)` captures one or more digit (greedy)

```
df['Item Code'] = df['Item Code'].str.extract(r'(?:^|\s)(\d+)', expand=False)
```

Note that the values of 'Item Code' are still stings after the extraction. If you want to convert them to integers use [`Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html?highlight=astype#pandas.Series.astype).

```
df['Item Code'] = df['Item Code']str.extract(r'(?:\s|^)(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int)
```

**Output**

```
>>> df

   ID  Price Item Code
0   1   3.60     80986
1   2   4.30     45772
2   3   0.60      9778
3   4   9.78     48989
4   5   3.44       545
5   6   3.44       509
```

Comment: It is important to note here that "Item Code" still has a string data type. The original poster will need to change the data type to INT or whichever if required on any downstream analyses.

Comment: @AndrewHamel good point, thanks! I will add it to the answer.

Comment: Hello, this solution works! Except when there characters have a number in them as well. Is there a way to ignore the number in the string of characters? i.e 'd.3 87678' ---> '87678'

Comment: @BobbyPlourde Try `r'\b(\d+)\b'` instead. `'\b'` denotes a word boundary.

Comment: @HarryPlotter I got the same output. It still only takes the first number to appear.

Comment: try `df['Item Code'].str.extract(r'(^|\s+)(\d+)')[1].astype(int)`

Comment: @hpchavaz thanks for the suggestion! I will update the answer with a very similar one.

Comment: @BobbyPlourde try the suggestion of hpchavaz

Comment: @HarryPlotter that suggestion worked! Here was my final code-  `df['Item Code']=df['Item Code'].str.extract(r'(^|\s+)(\d+)')[1]`

Comment: @BobbyPlourde I'm glad it worked! I've updated the answer with a very similar pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think using a regex is the solution:

```
import re

dt["Item code"] = list(map(lambda x:int(re.findall("\d+", x)[0]), dt["Item code"]))
```